# in my WordPress customized plugin "Function name must be a string " I am using $get_the_author_meta()

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, fatal-error

I am creating WordPress plugin and I have added a custom field called balance to my users table , now when I try to get the value from this field using `$xxx=$get_the_author_meta('balance',$user_id);`
it gives me the following error
php Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string.
cant figure out the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added a `$` sign before `get_the_author_meta()` function.

This will be:

`$xxx = get_the_author_meta('balance',$user_id);`